# How to get values in json array in following structure

Tags: android, json

I need to fetch values of  imagesall. How to do so. Here is json structure

```
 {
        "status": "true",
        "product": [
            {
                "hostid": "65",
                "user_id": "39",
                "hometype": "Paying Guest",
                "roomtype": "Private Room",


                "imagesall": [
                    "http://hostguesthome.com/uploadedfile/hostImages/user_94Chrysanthemum.jpg",
                    "http://hostguesthome.com/uploadedfile/hostImages/user_15Desert.jpg",
                    "http://hostguesthome.com/uploadedfile/hostImages/user_13Hydrangeas.jpg"
                ]
            },
```

What i have done so far is as following but it is giving error . no value for imagesall . I am trying to find first value inside imagesall array.

Here is my code :

```
JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(jsonStr);

                    // Getting JSON Array node
                    contacts = jsonObj.getJSONArray("product");

                    // looping through All Contacts
                    for (int i = 0; i < contacts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject c = contacts.getJSONObject(i);

                        JSONArray img_ar = c.getJSONArray("imagesall");


                              System.out.println("++++++"+img_ar.get(0).toString());

                              Log.i("This is DETAIL", ""+img_ar.get(0).toString());
```

Error log is :

```
06-24 16:13:45.476: W/System.err(14536): org.json.JSONException: No value for imagesall
06-24 16:13:45.476: W/System.err(14536):    at org.json.JSONObject.get(JSONObject.java:355)
06-24 16:13:45.477: W/System.err(14536):    at org.json.JSONObject.getJSONArray(JSONObject.java:549)
06-24 16:13:45.477: W/System.err(14536):    at com.example.hostguestapp.Details$Getdetails.doInBackground(Details.java:101)
06-24 16:13:45.478: W/System.err(14536):    at com.example.hostguestapp.Details$Getdetails.doInBackground(Details.java:1)
06-24 16:13:45.478: W/System.err(14536):    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:288)
06-24 16:13:45.478: W/System.err(14536):    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
06-24 16:13:45.478: W/System.err(14536):    at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
06-24 16:13:45.478: W/System.err(14536):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
06-24 16:13:45.479: W/System.err(14536):    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
06-24 16:13:45.479: W/System.err(14536):    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:841)
```

Comment: try with `img_ar.getString(0)`

Comment: still the same error

Comment: Please post your whole code.

Comment: @shoeb .. it is giving error on this line  JSONArray img_ar = c.getJSONArray("imagesall");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this-

```
            try {
                JSONObject _jObject = new JSONObject("YOUR_JSON_STRING");
                String _status = _jObject.getString("status");
                JSONArray _jArray = _jObject.getJSONArray("product");
                for (int i = 0; i < _jArray.length(); i++) {
                    JSONObject _jSubObj = _jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    String _hostid = _jSubObj.getString("hostid");
                    String _user_id = _jSubObj.getString("user_id");
                    String _hometype = _jSubObj.getString("hometype");
                    String _roomtype = _jSubObj.getString("roomtype");
                    JSONArray _jArrImg = _jSubObj.getJSONArray("imagesall");
                    for (int j = 0; j < _jArrImg.length(); j++) {
                        String _img = _jArrImg.getString(j);
                    }

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
```

Comment: json is valid on jsonlint and the structure is same as i posted